# Fail to update the fields in the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm trying to create the function to update user details. but the database transaction in the model fails. It just pops out failure message without giving any db errors or anything.

Is there a way to view db logs for debugging in model like var_dump in controller

controller

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class edit_account extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('medit_account');
}

function index() {

}

function edit_dept_officer() {

    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
 //      retrieve data from db to edit from             
    $table = 'department_officer';
    $user_data = $this->medit_account->get_current_user($table, $user_id);

    var_dump($user_data);

    $userid = $user_data[0]->OfficerID;

    $data = array(
        'officer_no' => $user_data[0]->officer_no,
        'first_name' => $user_data[0]->first_name,
        'last_name' => $user_data[0]->last_name,
        'contact_no' => $user_data[0]->contact_no,
    );
    var_dump($userid);
    //validation rules
 //        $this->form_validation->set_rules('officer_no', 'Officer ID ', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name ', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name ', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_no', 'Contact Number', 'trim|required|numeric');

    var_dump($data);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //fail validation
//            $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('edit_account_dept_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
//            var_dump('point');
    } else {

//          pass validation
        $officer_no = $user_data[0]->officer_no;
        $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name', TRUE);
        $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name' , TRUE);
        $contact_no = $this->input->post('contact_no', TRUE);

        $array1 = array(
            'officer_no' => $officer_no,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'contact_no' => $contact_no,
        );
        var_dump($array1);

        echo 'braekpoint';

        $tableid = 'OfficerID';
        var_dump($userid);
        var_dump($tableid);
        var_dump($table);


        if($this->medit_account->update_user( $userid,  $array1)) {
            // user creation ok
            echo 'success';
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Department Officer is created !!!</div>');

 //                $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('edit_account_dept_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

//                redirect('edit_account');
        } else {
            // user creation failed
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">There was a problem creating the Department Officer. Please try again.!!!</div>');
            echo 'fail';
            // send error to the view
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('edit_account_dept_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
}
```

model

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class medit_account extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_current_user($table,$user_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where('LoginId', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $user_data = $query->result();
    return $user_data;
}

public function update_user( $userid,  $array1) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->where('OfficerID', $userid);
    $this->db->update('department_officer', $array1);

    return ;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Which line?

Comment: it doesn't show any line, just pops the failure msg, which is the else part of if condition in **if($this->medit_account->update_user( $userid,  $array1)) ** .  @paskl

Comment: Your method "update_user" doesnt return any value, which means the call in an condition never works. Hence you always are in the "else". Did you check the database if nothing happens?

Comment: Do you really need a transaction? if yes then you need to end it -- look in the codeigniter manual for that line of code. Also keep in mind that you can check if there was an update with IF $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' -- BUT if you send duplicate information - as in nothing in the database was actually changed with the update - then that will be false.

Comment: Even with the transaction start removed same thing happens, checked the manual for update code and i don't see any errors. There was no change in the database entry. @cartalot

Comment: Thats the problem I'm facing, i'm trying to figure which line is creating the error in the model. but have no idea how to view which lines fails the condition @paskl

Comment: I just told you. Your method doesnt return anything. How can you expect to use it in a condition then? Its like "Hi mom, can I have a sandwhich?" - "You remember Mom doesnt exist" - "OK, thanks, Dad!"